# invalid cast exception, storing colordialog value in textbox

Tags: vb.net

why do i get an error here?

```
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & Str(ColorDialog1.Color)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & Str(ColorDialog1.Color.ToString())

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color_members.aspx

Color is a type that stores information about a color, so you have to call ToString() to convert the value to a string.